# Removing '.git' directory from git repo?

Tags: git, mercurial, git-filter-branch, git-rewrite-history

I'm trying to migrate a git repo from Kiln to Github. I can add the new remote just fine, but when I try to push master to the new remote, I get the following error:

```
Counting objects: 8691, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (3000/3000), done.
remote: error: object a9ee490ac00987835de30bdbc851da5e8d45d28b:contains '.git'
remote: fatal: Error in object
error: pack-objects died of signal 13
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:Account/repo.git'
```

Commit `a9ee490ac00987835de30bdbc851da5e8d45d28b` has the following files in it:

```
.git/
CHANGELOG.md
JSONKit.h
JSONKit.m
README.md
```

Obviously someone in the past, using `hg`, checked in a full git repo in a subdirectory.

I'd like to just kill that directory entirely, but am having trouble removing that file from the git history.

The answer in [pushing a git repo fails with error: contains '.git'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14728751/pushing-a-git-repo-fails-with-error-contains-git) doesn't help, because I've the the repo as a git repo, not a mercurial one.

I tried `git filter-branch --index-filter 'git rm -r --cached --ignore-unmatch .git'`, but I get the error:

```
Rewrite 7dbd0970d6c79215d11994b4a9b8091b2e954cfb (326/442)error: Invalid path 'Account/Libraries/ShareKit/Submodules/JSONKit/.git/HEAD'
error: Invalid path 'Account/Libraries/ShareKit/Submodules/JSONKit/.git/config'
error: Invalid path 'Account/Libraries/ShareKit/Submodules/JSONKit/.git/description'
error: Invalid path 'Account/Libraries/ShareKit/Submodules/JSONKit/.git/hooks/applypatch-msg.sample'
error: Invalid path 'Account/Libraries/ShareKit/Submodules/JSONKit/.git/hooks/commit-msg.sample'
error: Invalid path 'Account/Libraries/ShareKit/Submodules/JSONKit/.git/hooks/post-update.sample'
error: Invalid path 'Account/Libraries/ShareKit/Submodules/JSONKit/.git/hooks/pre-applypatch.sample'
error: Invalid path 'Account/Libraries/ShareKit/Submodules/JSONKit/.git/hooks/pre-commit.sample'
error: Invalid path 'Account/Libraries/ShareKit/Submodules/JSONKit/.git/hooks/pre-rebase.sample'
error: Invalid path 'Account/Libraries/ShareKit/Submodules/JSONKit/.git/hooks/prepare-commit-msg.sample'
error: Invalid path 'Account/Libraries/ShareKit/Submodules/JSONKit/.git/hooks/update.sample'
error: Invalid path 'Account/Libraries/ShareKit/Submodules/JSONKit/.git/index'
error: Invalid path 'Account/Libraries/ShareKit/Submodules/JSONKit/.git/info/exclude'
error: Invalid path 'Account/Libraries/ShareKit/Submodules/JSONKit/.git/logs/HEAD'
error: Invalid path 'Account/Libraries/ShareKit/Submodules/JSONKit/.git/logs/refs/heads/master'
error: Invalid path 'Account/Libraries/ShareKit/Submodules/JSONKit/.git/objects/pack/pack-43fac03d375df5c1e380c5e522ba6bcb9b4e1ec1.idx'
error: Invalid path 'Account/Libraries/ShareKit/Submodules/JSONKit/.git/objects/pack/pack-43fac03d375df5c1e380c5e522ba6bcb9b4e1ec1.pack'
error: Invalid path 'Account/Libraries/ShareKit/Submodules/JSONKit/.git/packed-refs'
error: Invalid path 'Account/Libraries/ShareKit/Submodules/JSONKit/.git/refs/heads/master'
error: Invalid path 'Account/Libraries/ShareKit/Submodules/JSONKit/.git/refs/remotes/origin/HEAD'
```

and history doesn't seem to be changed. I'm at the limit of my git knowledge. Can anyone help?

Comment: Is the repo open-source? are you able to share a copy of it?

Comment: Ah, no need to share a copy of the repo in question, I've managed to construct a Git repository with the same kind of bad tree, which I can use for testing purposes.

Comment: possible duplicate of [pushing a git repo fails with error: contains '.git'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14728751/pushing-a-git-repo-fails-with-error-contains-git)

Comment: Thanks @dana! I was facing the *exact* same problem right now (the .git folder having been added by mistake previously, while the repo was still in hg)

Answer (score 39):

Use the [BFG Repo-Cleaner](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/), a simpler, faster alternative to `git-filter-branch` specifically designed for removing files from Git history.

Carefully follow the steps here: https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/#usage - but the core bit is just this: download the [BFG jar](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/#download) (requires Java 8 or above) and run this command:

```
$ java -jar bfg.jar --delete-folders .git --delete-files .git --no-blob-protection my-repo.git
```

Your entire repository history will be scanned, and any file or folder named `.git` will be removed. I've tested this against a specially-constructed [test repo](https://github.com/rtyley/bfg-repo-cleaner/blob/v1.6.0/bfg/src/test/resources/sample-repos/badRepoContainingDotGitFolder.git.zip) containing a `.git` folder, and it worked just fine.

Thanks to Michel Jouvin for [reminding me](https://github.com/rtyley/bfg-repo-cleaner/issues/60#issuecomment-65919279) that *files* named '.git' are also illegal in Git (and the error message reported by Git doesn't make it immediately obvious that they *are* files, rather than folders), I've updated this answer to reflect that.

*Full disclosure: I'm the author of the BFG Repo-Cleaner.*

Comment: I had the same problem and this solution did the trick for me.

Comment: Thanks!! I had the exact same problem too and this saved my life. If I could I'd mark this as the right answer.

Comment: I tried the git filter-branch approach and it did not work, but using the bfg repo-cleaner worked like a charm. thanks!

Comment: Thanks! I agree with @JanSegre, this should definitely be marked as the correct answer. Worked like a charm for me.

Comment: This one did the trick for me too. Super easy and fast approach. Although I did not use the --no-blob-protection as it was a repo i just imported from Perforce.

Comment: Also worked the first time for me - thanks for the great tool Roberto!

Comment: This worked for me.  Big thank you.  BFG tool did the job.

Answer (score 2):

As of git 2.2.22 the way to do this is with the [git-filter-repo](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo) tool.

Easy and fast:

```
git filter-repo --force --invert-paths --path-glob '*/.git' --path '.git'
```

Comment: Worked like a charm.  Thanks!  Only required 4.5 mins for an 18-GB repo for me.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried with the following command ?

```
git filter-branch --tree-filter 'rm -Rf .git' HEAD
```

[git filter-branch documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-filter-branch.html) indicates that this would be slower than `--index-filter`, but it could do the job.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think this approach will work- running against a test repo that I constructed, this is the output I get: $ git filter-branch --tree-filter 'rm -Rf foo/.git' HEAD .....
Rewrite 6652877677cf01a7b668704134d5e8bb62bfe317 (6/6)error: Invalid path 'foo/.git/folder/zero'
error: Invalid path 'foo/.git/hero'
error: Invalid path 'foo/.git/zero'
Ignoring path foo/.git/folder/zero
Ignoring path foo/.git/hero
Ignoring path foo/.git/zero

WARNING: Ref 'refs/heads/master' is unchanged

Comment: ...so it looks like even using 'git filter-branch --tree-filter' has the problem that @dana encountered in the question. I would think that  using The BFG is probably a better idea at this point.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to handle the case where a Mercurial (Hg) repo has a .git folder embedded in it is to first "fix" the Hg repo before exporting to Git. [@laurens-holst](https://stackoverflow.com/users/310500/laurens-holst) has [a great way of doing this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14732374/31629).

If the .git folder was in the root of your project, then your create a text file, `my-filemap` that looks like:

```
exclude ".git"
```

Enable the Convert extension in your .hgrc file:

```
[extensions]
convert =
```

Then filter out the .git folder using the Hg convert extension:

```
hg convert --filemap my-filemap originalrepo newrepo
```

Now you can export from newrepo and won't have the issue of the embedded .git folder.

You can also use `git fsck` to make sure the new Git repo is ok before pushing it.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it kiln will let you clone a repository as either git or Mercurial these days, so clone it as mercurial, use the [mercurial filemap solution you already found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14728751/pushing-a-git-repo-fails-with-error-contains-git) push that Mercurial repo *as a new repo* to Kiln and then clone it down as git.  Then you'll have a git repo you can push to github.