# Git remote: error: object contains '.git'

Tags: git, github

When pushing to Github I encounter the following error

```
Counting objects: 16780, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (10936/10936), done.
remote: error: object f4ac3e31afb08298c6cd2ac04c6853940bbab3f6:contains '.git'
remote: fatal: Error in object
error: pack-objects died of signal 13
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:omarshammas/repo_name.git'
```

This git object `f4ac3e31afb08298c6cd2ac04c6853940bbab3f6` complains that it contains the `.git` folder. I imagine this was caused when migrating over from mercurial to git.

Anyways, I tried removing the `.git` folder from the history using

```
git filter-branch --force --index-filter \
'git rm -r --cached --ignore-unmatch .git' \
--prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat -- --all
```

But I still encounter the error.

I haven't had a problem pushing to other remotes such as (bitbucket / heroku). Github apparently has more stringent validations in place.

Not sure if it matters, but the object that is complaining is a tree object.

```
> git show f4ac3e31afb08298c6cd2ac04c6853940bbab3f6

tree f4ac3e31afb08298c6cd2ac04c6853940bbab3f6

.git/
MIT-LICENSE
README.textile
assets/
init.rb
install.rb
lib/
tasks/
```

Thanks

Comment: Check this stackoverflow answers:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16821649/removing-git-directory-from-git-repo
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14728751/pushing-a-git-repo-fails-with-error-contains-git

Comment: @abrasadera the first link did the trick. thanks! If you add it as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: stack marked my answer as trivial so must stay as it is in comment - glad to help you :)